# What chemical to use to recycle microplates used to grow bacteria

Tags: biochemistry, bacteriology

We grow bacteria (*Escherichia coli*) in polypropylene or polystyrene microplates with an optical bottom for some experiments (liquid culture).

I would like to try and recycle those microplates to be able to reuse them.

What chemical could be used? Ethanol, which I expected to kill the bacteria, doesn't work well as it leaves some deposit of bacteria aggregates. I was thinking about a chemical to lyse the bacteria, but [I read here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5480/bacterial-cell-lysis-what-solution-to-use) that it requires lysozyme to be efficient. I am rather looking for an inexpensive solution.

Comment: Would soap and hot water work? I assume you want to avoid scrubbing so as not to scratch the plates and change their optical properties

Comment: Are these in liquid culture or in/on solid media?  You could try NaOH and SDS - *a la* plasmid preparation lysis.

Comment: @acvill Thank you for the suggestion, I could try that. Indeed, we would like to avoid altering the optical properties of the optical phase.

Comment: @bob1 Yes, experiments are performed in liquid media (I have updated the question accordingly). The NaOH + SDS is a very good suggestion, thank you. I will try that.

Comment: Let us know how it goes by self- answering.